# removing blank bottom menu and extra space from the front page of wordpress site

Tags: html, css, wordpress

My site is thespindrifters.com

There was originally a bottom menu but I made this blank but wondering if anyone knows how I can remove it? I am using a child theme and am not sure about removing code from the parent one so is there a work around at all?

Also there seems to be a lot of excess space between my page at the top and the 'Recent posts'  section - and i cant seem to remove it - have tried adding code to child theme to remove padding but this didnt work.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Can add screenshot for more clarification?

Comment: Hi, I cant screenshot for some reason. if you take a look at the site - thespindrifters.com it is below the spinning picture gallery and directly above the recent posts featured content area.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin appearance and find the menu there. delete it. If can't delete (if it is the main-menu) then check it's position, select a different position from dropdown and change it's name.

That will hide it for sure.